# Plotting complex values of functions with a real parameter in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I couldn't manage to make Wolfram Alpha plot complex values of functions with a real parameter *in the complex plane*. Instead, I always get (separated) representations of the real and the imaginary part of such a function.

E.g. $e^{i \phi}$ should result in the unitary circle, but Wolfram Alpha shows the cosine and the sine curve.

Which is the suitable code? Are there free tools apart Wolfram Alpha to show such plots?

Comment: Do You want a software or a method to sketch your maps?

Comment: If you separate the real and imaginary parts, you can do for example [parametric plot (cos(t), sin(t))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(cos(t),+sin(t))).

Comment: To plot a parametrically defined path in the complex plane, like the unit circle, using WolframAlpha, you might try: `plot (re(e^(it)),im(e^(it))),t=0..2pi`. As is often the case, you will receive several "pods" of output. When I just tried this, the *second* pod (labeled "parametric plot") was exactly what you want.

Comment: If you want free, online tool with more programmatic control, you might try the Sage Cell server. You can generate your desired output like so:

[`t = var('t'); parametric_plot((real(exp(I*t)),imag(exp(I*t))),[t,0,2*pi])`](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=gawaik)

Comment: If you really want to plot complex functions, turn to Matlab, which handles complex numbers seamlessly. For example, z=exp(i*theta); plot(z).

Comment: Thanks specially to Mark McClure. This is exactly what I needed.